# How to get exact x,y coordinates based on x,y coordinates coming from server for drawing the overlay in WebRtc

Tags: android

I am developing application for remote expert using webrtc, where remote expert will draw something on surface view on desktop side and other side, mobile client will get x,y to draw the overlay. The issue is, i am not able to draw on the exact position, because the screen sizes for both clients does not match. Any pointers, please help..

Comment: Add some code samples please

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the dimensions of desktop client and send it to mobile client, in this way you can scale up/down on mobile client. For ex:

```
       mobileX = (desktopX * (mobileDeviceWidth/ desktopWidth)).toInt()
```

Comment: Hi Ashish, Thanks.. this is working with little difference in positioning with scaling type SCALE_ASPECT_FIT. But screen is not full screen. In full screen i.e. with SCALE_ASPECT_FILL or BALANCED positioning gets misplaced again.